# Optimize log entropy calculation in sparse matrix

Tags: c++, c, math

I have a 3007 x 1644 dimensional matrix of terms and documents. I am trying to assign weights to frequency of terms in each document so I'm using this log entropy formula http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_indexing#Term_Document_Matrix (See entropy formula in the last row).

I'm successfully doing this but my code is running for >7 minutes.
Here's the code:

```
int N = mat.cols();
for(int i=1;i<=mat.rows();i++){
    double gfi = sum(mat(i,colon()))(1,1); //sum of occurrence of terms
    double g =0;
    if(gfi != 0){// to avoid divide by zero error

        for(int j = 1;j<=N;j++){
            double tfij = mat(i,j);
            double pij = gfi==0?0.0:tfij/gfi;
            pij = pij + 1; //avoid log0
            double G = (pij * log(pij))/log(N);
            g = g + G;
        }
    }

    double gi = 1 - g;
    for(int j=1;j<=N;j++){
        double tfij = mat(i,j) + 1;//avoid log0
        double aij = gi * log(tfij);
        mat(i,j) = aij;
    }
}
```

Anyone have ideas how I can optimize this to make it faster? Oh and mat is a RealSparseMatrix from amlpp matrix library.

**UPDATE**
Code runs on Linux mint with 4gb RAM and AMD Athlon II dual core

Running time before change: > 7mins

After @Kereks answer: 4.1sec

Comment: Stop copying all the data around!

Comment: There are only ~5M operations, and it should take a couples second in a normal computer. Have you use -O3 to optimize your compilation? Also what matrix lib arre you using

Comment: I am currently optimizing with O2 but let me give that a try. @Kerrek Goood point too thanks

Comment: I'm using amlpp http://amlpp.sourceforge.net/ It has similar syntax with matlab but I'm not sure how it fast it is.

Comment: @Aki I've updated that. Speed is still the same though.

Comment: What's your profiler's opinion on the subject?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a very naive rewrite that removes some redundancies:

```
int const N = mat.cols();
double const logN = log(N);

for (int i = 1; i <= mat.rows(); ++i)
{
    double const gfi = sum(mat(i, colon()))(1, 1);  // sum of occurrence of terms
    double g = 0;

    if (gfi != 0)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= N; ++j)
         {
            double const pij = mat(i, j) / gfi + 1;
            g += pij * log(pij);
        }
        g /= logN;
    }

    for (int j = 1; j <= N; ++j)
    {
        mat(i,j) = (1 - g) * log(mat(i, j) + 1);
    }
}
```

Also make sure that the matrix data structure is sane (e.g. a flat array accessed in strides; *not* a bunch of dynamically allocated rows).

Also, I think the first `+ 1` is a bit silly. You know that `x -> x * log(x)` is continuous at zero with limit zero, so you should write:

```
double const pij = mat(i, j) / gfi;
if (pij != 0) { g += pij + log(pij); }
```

In fact, you might even write the first inner `for` loop like this, avoiding a division when it isn't needed:

```
        for (int j = 1; j <= N; ++j)
        {
            if (double pij = mat(i, j))
            {
                pij /= gfi;
                g += pij * log(pij);
            }
        }
```

Comment: +1 It runs in only 4.2 seconds now. Amazing! Thank you.

Comment: I included the O3 flag though

Comment: @unekwu Please post a timing with your original optimization, thanks

Comment: "x -> x * log(x)" won't be undefined since you already added 1 to pij

Comment: @unekwu: I'm saying to get rid of the "+1", which is mathematically weird anyway. See the added suggestion.

Comment: @DieterLücking Running time before the changes was >7 minutes. I didn't wait for it complete.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thats right. +1 is absent in the formula too. I was trying to avoid log0. Thanks for your help

Comment: 4.1 secs after changing the first inner loop